# Magento import products from Excel sheet

Tags: magento, import, export, product

I recently got a Excel sheet for some products with at least 900 new records.
Now the problem is wether I shall type this manually in the backend or create an own import script for this?

I tried it with the existing Import/Export and only selected that fields I would need to create a master template and fill the new data into it.

But that new master template doesn't look like I can use it. There are much much more fields exported then I would need to import.

Is there any other way to import an Excel sheet that isn't really conform to that from magento import/export one?

Answer (score 0):

Use Magmi to import the products :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Ok I've installed it and tried to import my Excel sheet saved as a CSV. And it didn't worked. Magmi said it imported 12 records but I couldn't found one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSV is UTF-8 encoded and in csv format.
Else you will getting loads of errors if you are going to use magmi.
Also study about how to use magmi before starting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post, here I am happy to share reply from Our Magento team lead:

"One can import data sheet using Magento Import/Export profiles but in this case you would need to convert your excel file to CSV first. 
Next step: please change columns names to match Magento product attributes codes.

Required attributes are the following:

store;

websites;

attribute_set;

type;

category_ids;

price;

weight;

sku;

name;

status;

visibility;

tax_class_id;

description;

short_description;

store_id;

another way to get correct CSV template file is to create a simple product and run export profile.

You will get export_produtcs.csv file where you can find all necessary columns."

Hope this helps,

Thank you

Jen Zorina

Itera Research